# related drop down error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to use javascript/jquery to create a loan calculator
i have this function

```
function setOptions(chosen, selbox) {

selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option(' ',' ');
setTimeout(setOptions(' ',document.myform.optthree),5);
}
if (chosen == "1") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option(' ','11');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Yes','12');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('No','13');
setTimeout(setOptions('11',document.myform.optthree),5);
setTimeout(setOptions('11',document.myform.optfour),5);
setTimeout(setOptions('11',document.myform.optfive),5);
}
.....

}
```

and i am using this javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "select[name='optone']" ).change(function() {

 setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value,document.myform.opttwo);

});
});
```

and this html

```
<form name="myform">
<select name="optone" size="1">
        <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1">Salaried</option>
        <option value="2">Self Employed</option>
        <option value="3">Professional</option>
        <option value="4">House Wife</option>
    </select><br />
<select name="opttwo" size="1">
        <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
    </select>
 </form>
```

i am getting this error:

[image]

any help please, should i define any object or something?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you add form HTML?

Comment: are you sure u've defined "document.myform" ?

Comment: done, please check again

Comment: Error is pretty clear: `document.myform` is undefined

Comment: isnt defined here ? <form name="myform">
<select name="optone" size="1">

Comment: no  you must give it an id `<form id="myform" name="myform">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.myform` is undefined

With jQuery your function will be:

```
$( "select[name='optone']" ).change(function() {

   setOptions($(this).val(), $("select[name='opttwo']")[0]);

});
```

UPDATE

`this` - already contains an element which the event targeted on (`select[name='optone']`)

`$(this)` - make this element as jQuery object

`.val()` - get selected value of `select` element

`$("select[name='opttwo']")` - get `select` element with name "opttwo", it is jQuery object

`$("select[name='opttwo']")[0]` - get a DOM element from jQuery object. But beware if you have multiple forms with name "opttwo" this will return only the first one.

Comment: thank you, it works for me, can you explain why we did it this way? thank you

Comment: @user1000744 who "we" and what "did it" ?